# scom 2012 You have specified the wrong server for this operation

Tags: exchange-server-2010, scom

we are getting the following error in scom 2012.

The AD Health Set has detected a problem with mailbox.eu.domainname.com at 10/8/2013 5:41:37 AM. The Health Manager is reporting that ActiveDirectoryConnectivityConfigDCProbe/mailbox.eu.domainname.com Failed with Error message: Received a referral to eu.domainname.com when requesting DC=eu,DC=domainname,DC=com from dc1.us.domainname.com You have specified the wrong server for this operation

**So we have the following AD set up**

**root:** domainname.com

**child domain**: us (1 mailbox server used to keep mail contacts for Office365)+

**child domain**: eu  (all Exchange server are here but one mailbox server)

We get this error on 2 Exchange 2013 mailbox servers and 1 Exchange 2013 cas server

Here is a break down of our Exchange org. We are moving to Exchange 2013 from Exchange 2010

**domain.com:** has 2 HUB/CAS both Exchange 2010

**us:** 1 Mailbox Exchange 2013 and 1 mailbox Exchange 2010

**eu:** 3 Mailbox Exchange 2013 and 3 Mailbox Exchange 2010, 3 CAS Exchange 2013 and 3 CAS Exchange 2010

when we are done with Exchange 2010 we will have the following

**domain.com:** 0 Exchange servers

**us:** 1 Mailbox Exchange 2013

**eu:** 3 Mailbox Exchange 2013, 3 CAS Exchange 2013

Now that i have given some back ground you can see that the dc1 is in the wrong domain. The accounts in dc1.us.domainname.com don't exist on mailbox.eu.domainname.com

Answer (score 0):

AD monitoring is buggy a lot, so first of all you should clear agents